# SwiftUI Switch case use TextField differ Value

Tags: swift, swiftui

Friends, I have a survey information from Apiden, while showing them there is a structure like the following, if the incoming data type is "text", I need to show textfield and get different answers for each question.

```
 switch anket.type {
                        case "text" :
                                TextField("Answer", text: $answer)
/// This textfield appears for multiple questions, I have to get different answers for each question.
                            }
                        case "radio-group":
}
```

MY MODEL :

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct AnketModel: Identifiable,Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    let ratingGroupStageID: Int?
    let formTitle: String?
    let answerStatusID, ratingToolFormID: Int?
    let formfields: [Formfield]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ratingGroupStageID
        case formTitle
        case answerStatusID
        case ratingToolFormID
        case formfields
    }
}

// MARK: - Formfield
struct Formfield: Identifiable,Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    let key, type: String?
    let subtype: String?
    let required: Bool?
    let label: String?
    let placeholder: String?
    let maxlength: Int?
    let conditionoptionid: String?
    let displayed: Bool?
    let description: String?
    let multiple: Bool?
    let order: Int?
    let directTextEdit: Bool?
    let values: [Value]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key, type, subtype
        case required
        case label, placeholder, maxlength, conditionoptionid, displayed
        case description
        case multiple, order, directTextEdit, values
    }
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let label, value: String?
}
```

MY VİEW :

```
    struct AnketEkraniViewModel: View {
    var anketModel : [Formfield]
    @State var selectedRadio = ""
    @State var openSelectedSoru = ""
    @State var checkBoxValue = ""
    @State private var deneme = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(self.anketModel, id:\.id){anket in
                VStack {
                    Group{
                        if anket.conditionoptionid == nil || anket.conditionoptionid == selectedRadio || anket.conditionoptionid == openSelectedSoru || anket.conditionoptionid == checkBoxValue{
                                HStack{
                                        Text("\(anket.order ?? 0)")
                                        if anket.type == "custom-checkbox" {
        //                                    CustomCheckBoxComponentClass(isTriggered: $isTriggered, index: $checkboxIndex)
                                        }
                                        Text(anket.label ?? "")
                                        Text(anket.required == true ? "*" : "")
                                }.padding(3)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }
                    Group{
                        switch anket.type {
                        case "text" :
                                TextField("Gönder Be", text: $deneme)
                            }
                        case "radio-group":
//                            EmptyView()
                        case "custom-checkbox" :
                           EmptyView()
                            
                        case "textarea":
                            EmptyView()
                        case "date" :
                            EmptyView()
                        case "select" :
                            EmptyView()
                        case "number" :
                            EmptyView()

                        case "checkbox-group" :
                            EmptyView()
                        case .none:
                            EmptyView()
                        case .some(_):
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole view is as above, I show my views according to the .type value from Api, but I got stuck in this part, where I need to get a different value for each question. I tried some ways but unfortunately did not get results.

Comment: Can you provide more details what error/blockers you are having? Is it decoding? Or is it the switch statement?

Comment: Also, please review these two pages: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Asking questions well will go a long way toward getting an actual answer.